# how get to next form after submit but it's on same page

Tags: html, forms

I want to make a survey based on forms, in which I try to get the new (next) form after a submit on the first form like below.

```
<form id="pass" action="form.html" method="get">
---some code for users to select answers--
<button type="submit" form="nextpass" value="next">
</form>
<form id="nextpass" action="form.html" method="get">
```

Both forms are displayed on the same page, but when I press the next button, I get the error "cannot get /".

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you not actually want to submit the forms, but only jump to a specific section of the page, or maybe even put the focus on a specific form field? Then use anchor links, not buttons.

Comment: i do want of course, that's the purpose of survey :) the submit thing will be put at end of forms completed, but what i'm asking is multiple forms when "next" after completed each form, for example: i completed a form then i click next to another form (it's on same page / same survey subject) however i could use anchor links in that case but i don't know if it's possible to break page for each form in html (br with line-height would do it but it seems uncomfortable for me).

Comment: You could specify a `min-height: 100vh` for the form or a parent container element, so that each will cover at least one screen height ...that would be a cheap&easy way to get the illusion of going to a next "page". If you want more than that, then I would suggest you go look for a JavaScript "tabbed interface" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to give each submit button a unique name. Then check if it was submitted, and process accordingly.

```
<form id="form_1" action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit_1" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="form_2" action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit_2" value="Submit" />
</form>


<?php

if( $_POST['submit_1'] ) {

// Do stuff

//hide form 1
echo "<style>#form_1{display:none}</style>";
        }
        else if( $_POST['submit_2'] ) {

          // Do stuff

        }

        ?>
```

Comment: using php or javascript i know that can be done, but i would rather like to know if can be done using html only (perhaps there is a feature for it by html5) ?

Comment: for submiting a form you need an server side language , you can't do by html only you would need ajax